# Take Screenshot of whole screen

Tags: android, screenshot

I have seen a lot of code snippets for taking a screenshot but was not able to get something which takes the screenshot of the whole screen and not just a view. It should replicate the way we get screenshot using ddms.

Can someone help?

Comment: On most phones, you will need superuser (Root) rights for this

Comment: Do you want to take screenshot by programmatically or through DDMS

Comment: Yes I want to take a screenshot programmatically preferably on non rooted device.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Android Screenshot library, which is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage). There wiki pages says library can be used to take screenshot of entire screen without the need of root level access, even from an unsigned application. I have never tried it though. You can use it as a starting point.

Comment: Well you still have to start it via ADB

Comment: Which means the device needs to be rooted right? Any way to get this working on non rooted device?

Answer (score 2):

```
        sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
        System.out.println("capturing");
        OutputStream outputstream = sh.getOutputStream();
        outputstream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/tos_processing.png".getBytes("ASCII"));
        outputstream.flush();
        outputstream.close();
        sh.waitFor();
        System.out.println("captured");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/tos_processing.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View v1 = view.getRootView();

                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);

                ImageView view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

                view2.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
}
```